# Content disappears after CSS blur animation in Chrome

Tags: css, css-animations

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3fb9kvj/6/) showing what's going on here. I'm trying to create an effect like that of focusing a lens in and out, but this will happen in Chrome (technically I've only tried Chromium, but they're essentially the same) even for a straightforward transition. After the animation, the content temporarily disappears and then reappears.

Does anyone know a fix for this? (*Please* verify it with the Fiddle in Chrome; I've tried multiple promising solutions, and all have failed.)

```css
.blur-animation {
  animation-name: focus;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes focus {
  0% {
    filter: blur(10px);
  }
  100% {
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
}

p {
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="blur-animation">
  <p>Hello, world</p>
</div>
```

### Update

Sorry guys, I should have tried this on Chrome rather than Chromium; the issue seems to be unique to Chromium and Android's Google app (not Chrome on Android). I don't expect a lot of people to be using Chromium, so it's not a big deal, although I am curious what caused it there.

Comment: It works fine in Chromium 67.0.3396.87 (64 bit)

Comment: Have you tried adding a line with the -webkit- prefix?

Comment: Works fine in Chromium 58.0.2988.0.

Comment: replace the `blur(0px)` with `blur(0.5px)`

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks that works like a charm and leaves it looking totally unblurred at the end. I was able to use 0.3px, but nothing much lower. Ya I tried -webkit-. I have Chromium 66.0.3359.181 running on Ubuntu 16.04. It seems to occur more often when I do a hard refresh. Anyway, not fully unblurring fixed the issue on my laptop and Chrome on my Android phone, which had the same issue

Comment: Actually, the Android problem was within Android's Google app, not its Chrome app. Also, Temani's trick is problematic because while the text looks clear in Chromium/the Google app, on Firefox it ends up looking blurry with `blur(0.5px)`. So that solution requires targeting (probably all webkit) browsers